# Form error doesnt display on template?

Tags: django, forms, validation

When I enter an invalid email adress I cant see an error message like "This is not an invalid email".

My comment_form.html:

```
{% load i18n %}

    <form action="/comment/create/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.errors }}
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}<p>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}
            <input type="hidden" name = "object_id" value="{{object_id}}"  />
            <input type="hidden" name= "next" value="{{ next }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Submit" %}">

    </form>
```

my post_detail.html:

```
extends "base.html" %}



{% block content %}
<div id="exap">


    {{ post.content }}

</div>
<div class="comment">
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <user>{{ comment.owner }}</user>
        {{ comment.content}}
    {% endfor %}


</div>
{% include "comment_form.html" %}


{% endblock %}
```

this is my comment.views

```
   def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        next = request.POST.get('next')
        if form.is_valid():
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="post", model="post")
            object_id = request.POST["object_id"]
            comment = Comment.objects.create(
                content_type = content_type,
                object_id = object_id,
                content = request.POST.get('content'),
                owner= request.POST.get('owner'),
                email = request.POST.get('email')
            )
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

Error message doesnt display in template ?

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: does the form validate correctly ? I mean does the server generate the error messages correctly ?

Comment: Please read the django tutorial before trying to code. You can use the django forms to your use here. Coming to your issue, in `except`, it should be `raise ValidationError('Invalid Email')`

Comment: I want to show error message in template but nothing happen !

Comment: Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: I did already. Where is my wrong, can you say? I want to display an error message to user if he/she enter an invalid email.

Comment: I dont think so, If you did, please implement the code the right way.

Comment: Why cant you just say my wrong ?

Comment: You are right, I am so sorry

Comment: You can get rid of so much of your code by using what django forms has to offer. I know it is painful to learn, but it is worth the effort, and you will be glad you learnt it. Good luck. I did point your error out here: `raise ValidationError('Invalid Email')` instead of `return False`, which I guess Daniel did a much better job explaining :)

Comment: Still no error message I see. I edited my views :/

Comment: You are doing a `return HttpResponseRedirect(next)` You need to `render()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

karthikr is trying to tell you what is wrong in the comments. You are not using the form to validate, so it won't show any errors. Instead of doing `if validateEmail(email)` you should have the email validation code inside the form class, and in the view you call `if form.is_valid()`.

Plus, when you do write the form's `clean_email` method, you should *not* be catching ValidationError: that's the way that errors are passed on to the form's errors list.